# URL matrix parameters and IOS

Tags: ios, html, tomcat, video-streaming

I am having problem with HTML 5 video on iPad.It is working in all major browsers.I have hosted a video on the Apache tomcat and try in the ipad.It works well.But I need to play a URL which is having matrix parameters in iPad.

It would be great if somebody can tell me,how can I host a video in the Apache tomcat and add some matrix parameters to it.It will work,If we add some junk query parameters with the URL.If we add matrix parameters in the same way,it will not work.

is there any specification says that,the matrix parameters will not work on iPad ?

Comment: could you provide an example-url?

Comment: https://beta-classroom-dev.qaols.phoenix.edu/VirtualRepository/CP1/context-info;T=831D8B107020BBEBE0400F0A32207789;P=0593d9ed-f762-44f9-b4ee-720fd93f261f;O=OSIRIS:30253288;A=2732caa2-ed7c-4773-92d1-910f996d0282;/file/8ef730cd-5b96-a69d-c4aa-a8e124ad6d7a/1/ECO564BETA_Price_Elasticity_final_h264.mp4?Username=scott&Password=scott
http://ec2-75-101-133-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ECO564BETA_Price_Elasticity_final_h264.mp4

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but our research may help someone else who chances across this.

We spent some time diagnosing problems playing back content on iOS/QuickTime using URLs with matrix parameters.  Specifically we were trying to play HLS content using URLs of the form 'http://myserver.mydomain.com/path;a=b.m3u8'

The video would play fine the first time, then fail the second (and every other) time.  If the matrix parameters weren't present, the video played fine every time.

Eventually we concluded it was an issue with iOS/QuickTime writing bad cache entries.  So the first time the server returned content, this was as cache miss on iOS/QuickTime so it played fine.  The next time, the server returned a 304 (not modified -- i.e. a cache hit), iOS/QuickTime tried to pull it from its cache, this failed so the video wouldn't play.

Our solution was to prevent client caching by setting the Cache-Control header to no-cache.  Another solution would be to not use matrix parameters.

Note that in terms of HLS, this bug only seemed to occur with the first m3u8 file loaded -- m3u8 URLs listed in the first m3u8 that contained matrix parameters seemed to play fine.